# Sox absolute paths and piping

Tags: c#, audio, merge, double-quotes, sox

I have a question about using [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). I need to mix many audio files and every file has it's own specific time when it should be added. I'm using piping and everything goes fine until I need to grab files with absolute paths with spaces in folder names. In this case I need to use double quotes twice (in path and to allocate piping). Here's example:

```
-m "initial.wav" "|sox "path with spaces\file1.mp3" -p pad 8.52 0" "|sox "another path with spaces\file2.mp3" -p pad 19.07 0" "|sox "file3.mp3" -p pad 36.52 0" "output.mp3"
```

And of course these quotes around file paths ruin command.
How can I fix this? Maybe it's possible to use single quotes somehow or maybe I'm missing something obvious...

Will may be useful to add that I'm runing sox from C# app, thus everything happens in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it is possible to escape the inner double quotes somehow. (Most?) *nix shells use the backslash for that purpose, i.e. you would write `... "|sox \"path with spaces/file1.mp3\" ..."`. Of course, Windows uses the backslash for different purposes (delimiting path components), so there may be a slightly different way to escape quotes.

Comment: Hah, my bad, I've tried escaping, but looks like made a typo at first time. But now it works as expected. Thank you!